# Video playback issue

Tags: cobalt

[cobalt] we are trying to implement starboard player module. When we start playing a YT clear content, we could hear the audio in the background, but we could not see the any video (we only see the spinning wheel on screen). If we disable the graphics layer (hacking), then we could see the video playing on the video layer. My question is, from sbplayer module, how could we inform cobalt (either state or event) so the browser would take off the graphics rendering that blocks the video?

We tried setting the state to kSbPlayerStatePresenting and we also sending the PTS but it did not help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can check output mode, the output mode should be kSbPlayerOutputModePunchOut for your requirement.